# .Net Dynamically Load DLL

Tags: vb.net, reflection, dll, assemblies

I am trying to write some code that will allow me to dynamically load DLLs into my application, depending on an application setting. The idea is that the database to be accessed is set in the application settings and then this loads the appropriate DLL and assigns it to an instance of an interface for my application to access.

This is my code at the moment:

```
        Dim SQLDataSource As ICRDataLayer
    Dim ass As Assembly = Assembly. _
    LoadFrom("M:\MyProgs\WebService\DynamicAssemblyLoading\SQLServer\bin\Debug\SQLServer.dll")

    Dim obj As Object = ass.CreateInstance(GetType(ICRDataLayer).ToString, True)
    SQLDataSource = DirectCast(obj, ICRDataLayer)

    MsgBox(SQLDataSource.ModuleName & vbNewLine & SQLDataSource.ModuleDescription)
```

I have my interface (ICRDataLayer) and the SQLServer.dll contains an implementation of this interface. I just want to load the assembly and assign it to the SQLDataSource object.

The above code just doesn't work. There are no exceptions thrown, even the Msgbox doesn't appear.
 I would've expected at least the messagebox appearing with nothing in it, but even this doesn't happen!

Is there a way to determine if the loaded assembly implements a specific interface. I tried the below but this also doesn't seem to do anything!

```
        For Each loadedType As Type In ass.GetTypes
        If GetType(ICRDataLayer).IsAssignableFrom(loadedType) Then
            Dim obj1 As Object = ass.CreateInstance(GetType(ICRDataLayer).ToString, True)
            SQLDataSource = DirectCast(obj1, ICRDataLayer)
        End If
    Next
```

---

**EDIT: New code from Vlad's examples:**

```
    Module CRDataLayerFactory
    Sub New()
    End Sub
    ' class name is a contract,
    ' should be the same for all plugins
    Private Function Create() As ICRDataLayer
        Return New SQLServer()
    End Function
End Module
```

Above is Module in each DLL, converted from Vlad's C# example.

Below is my code to bring in the DLL:

```
Dim SQLDataSource As ICRDataLayer
    Dim ass As Assembly = Assembly. _
    LoadFrom("M:\MyProgs\WebService\DynamicAssemblyLoading\SQLServer\bin\Debug\SQLServer.dll")

    Dim factory As Object = ass.CreateInstance("CRDataLayerFactory", True)
    Dim t As Type = factory.GetType
    Dim method As MethodInfo = t.GetMethod("Create")
    Dim obj As Object = method.Invoke(factory, Nothing)
    SQLDataSource = DirectCast(obj, ICRDataLayer)
```

---

**EDIT: Implementation based on Paul Kohler's code**

```
Dim file As String
        For Each file In Directory.GetFiles(baseDir, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            Dim assemblyType As System.Type
            For Each assemblyType In Assembly.LoadFrom(file).GetTypes

                Dim s As System.Type() = assemblyType.GetInterfaces
                For Each ty As System.Type In s

                    If ty.Name.Contains("ICRDataLayer") Then
                        MsgBox(ty.Name)
                        plugin = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyType), ICRDataLayer)
                        MessageBox.Show(plugin.ModuleName)
                    End If
                Next
```

I get the following error with this code:

Unable to cast object of type 'SQLServer.CRDataSource.SQLServer' to type 'DynamicAssemblyLoading.ICRDataLayer'.

The actual DLL is in a different project called SQLServer in the same solution as my implementation code. CRDataSource is a namespace and SQLServer is the actual class name of the DLL.
 The SQLServer class implements ICRDataLayer, so I don't understand why it wouldn't be able to cast it.
 Is the naming significant here, I wouldn't have thought it would be.

---

**Final Working code**

Contents of PluginUtility:

```
enter code here    Public Shared Function GetInstances1(Of Type)(ByVal baseDir As String, ByVal searchPattern As String) As System.Type()
    Dim tmpInstances As New List(Of Type)
    Try
        Dim file As String
        For Each file In Directory.GetFiles(baseDir, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            Dim assemblyType As System.Type
            For Each assemblyType In Assembly.LoadFrom(file).GetTypes

                Dim s As System.Type() = assemblyType.GetInterfaces
                Return s.ToArray()

            Next
        Next
    Catch exp As TargetInvocationException
        If (Not exp.InnerException Is Nothing) Then
            Throw exp.InnerException
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

Code to load the DLL:

```
enter code here
    Dim basedir As String = "M:\MyProgs\WebService\DynamicAssemblyLoading\SQLServer\bin\Debug\"
    Dim searchPattern As String = "*SQL*.dll"
    Dim plugin As CRDataLayer.ICRDataLayer

    Try
        Dim file As String
        For Each file In Directory.GetFiles(baseDir, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            Dim assemblyType As System.Type
            For Each assemblyType In Assembly.LoadFrom(file).GetExportedTypes

                If assemblyType.GetInterface("CRDataLayer.ICRDataLayer") IsNot Nothing Then
                    plugin = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyType), CRDataLayer.ICRDataLayer)
                    MessageBox.Show(plugin.ModuleDescription)
                End If

            Next
        Next
    Catch exp As TargetInvocationException
        If (Not exp.InnerException Is Nothing) Then
            Throw exp.InnerException
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Clipboard.SetText(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Don't use `ty.Name.Contains("ICRDataLayer")` - check that it "implements the type" with `assemblyType.GetInterface("your namespace etc.ICRDataLayer")` (seehttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcctb9t8.aspx) it will give you `Nothing` if its not implemented by the current Type. Also, the exception seems to indicate that the Interface is not implemented, are you using a shared DLL for that - it needs to be the same one. PK

Comment: Check the solution below again...

Comment: It works!

I ended up using your code Paul, it works exactly as I need it to.
For anyone who may come across this thread in the future, I will add my final code in to the original post so hopefully they can have an easier time getting this to work than I have.

Thankyou all for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 2 - This sample loads up a DLL from it current directory. 
There are 2 projects, 1 console application project and a "module" project (the module 'coppies' its DLL to the working directory of the console app).

The sample below simply demonstrates dynamically loading a DLL that implements an interface. The `IModule` interface just reports its name. `PlugInUtility.GetInstances(Of IModule)(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "*.Module.dll")` will create an instance of any `IModule` instance found in a DLL within the current directory ending with ".Module.dll". It's a reflected VB.NET version straight out of Mini SQL Query.

With that in mind something like:

```
Dim modules As IModule() = PlugInUtility.GetInstances(Of ICRDataLayer)(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "*.Server.dll")
```

Should satisfy your requirement. Then you just need to chose which one to execute!

***The code:***

**In "VB.LoaderDemo Colsole App"**

```
' IModule.vb
Public Interface IModule
    Property ModuleName() As String
End Interface

' PlugInUtility.vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection
Public Class PlugInUtility
    Public Shared Function GetInstances(Of T)(ByVal baseDir As String, ByVal searchPattern As String) As T()
        Dim tmpInstances As New List(Of T)
        Try
            Dim file As String
            For Each file In Directory.GetFiles(baseDir, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                Dim assemblyType As Type
                For Each assemblyType In Assembly.LoadFrom(file).GetTypes()
                    If (Not assemblyType.GetInterface(GetType(T).FullName) Is Nothing) Then
                        tmpInstances.Add(DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyType), T))
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Catch exp As TargetInvocationException
            If (Not exp.InnerException Is Nothing) Then
                Throw exp.InnerException
            End If
        End Try
        Return tmpInstances.ToArray()
    End Function
End Class

' MainModule.vb
Module MainModule
    Sub Main()
        Dim plugins As IModule() = PlugInUtility.GetInstances(Of IModule)(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "*.Module.dll")
        Dim m As IModule
        For Each m In plugins
            Console.WriteLine(m.ModuleName)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

**In "Sample1 DLL"** (references 'VB.LoaderDemo' for IModule)

```
Imports VB.LoaderDemo

Public Class MyModule1
    Implements IModule

    Dim _name As String

    Public Sub New()
        _name = "Sample 1, Module 1"
    End Sub

    Public Property ModuleName() As String Implements IModule.ModuleName
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

The output is:

```
> Sample 1, Module 1
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I have tried implementing your code, my effort has been attached to the main post along with error information as there is not enough room to fit it in a comment and you don't get formatting in a comment either.
 At least I am getting an error now, I've just not idea why!

Answer (score 3):

Is the type `ICRDataLayer` defined in the DLL you are going to load? If so, you seem to already reference the DLL in your project settings.

You need to work with just reflection:

```
Dim obj As Object = ass.CreateInstance("ICRDataLayer", True)
Dim t as Type = obj.GetType()
Dim method as MethodInfo = t.GetMethod("DoSomething")
method.Invoke(obj, ...)
```

---

Edit: If `ICRDataLayer` is implemented in the application, and the plugin just implements the interface, you need the plugin to provide a factory for you: (sorry for C# code, I am not familiar with VB.NET's syntax)

```
// in each of plugins:
static class CRDataLayerFactory // class name is a contract,
{                               // should be the same for all plugins
    static ICRDataLayer Create()
    {
        return new CRDataLayerImplementation();
    }
}
```

The application's code should look like this:

```
Dim factory As Object = ass.CreateInstance("CRDataLayerFactory", True)
Dim t as Type = factory.GetType()
Dim method as MethodInfo = t.GetMethod("Create")
Dim obj as Object = method.Invoke(factory, null)

SQLDataSource = DirectCast(obj, ICRDataLayer)
```

Comment: Thanks for that code Vlad, it makes a lot more sense now. Will try that out when I can.

Comment: I tried your code Vlad. Interestingly, if I debug, it gets to the 't as type' line and doesn't execute any code after it. No exceptions, no errors, it just stops processing any code that follows that line and brings up the form.
Even if I put in something simple like MessageBox.Show("Hello"), it doesn't get executed.
As stated in my reply to nobugz, I think VS may be broken! Will try a repair install and then try your code again.

Comment: Managed to get VS working again, just had to move the code to a button click event and all is now fine. Weird. I get an object reference not set error on the Dim t As Type=factory.GetType line, looks like the ass.CreateInstance isn't working. Any thoughts?
I have added my current code to the original post.

Comment: @hermiod: maybe you can step over that code in the debugger and look what will be returned by `CreateInstance`? What will be in the `obj`

Comment: after going over the CreateInstance line, obj is nothing.
I think my VS is still a little screwy as I'm not getting any state information on ass.CreateInstance.

Comment: Well, I suppose you should add namespace to your typename.
Something like CreateInstance("FactoryNamespace.CRDataLayerFactory", True), if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to look for in your code

- Debug through and check that the
  assembly is loaded correctly, in case
  it fails due to dependency checking
- Instead of using GetType, use GetExportedType so you have smaller subset to iterate through
- The CreateInstance should use your loadedType rather than the interface (you cant create object from an interface)
- Personally, I dont like naming my variable ass, I would shorten it to assem instead :)